# How do I send array of files by Unirest objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, unirest

I am using Unirest in my objective-c project.  It is a very small but handy library.

https://github.com/Mashape/unirest-obj-c

**However,  I can't wrap my mind around how to POST array of files with Unirest.**

If I were to build an HTML form, it will look like:

```
<input type="file" name="files[]" >
<input type="file" name="files[]" >
<input type="file" name="files[]" >
```

The file upload example from Unirest is:

```
NSDictionary* headers = @{@"accept": @"application/json"};
NSURL* file = nil;
NSDictionary* parameters = @{@"parameter": @"value", @"file": file};

UNIHTTPJsonResponse *response = [[UNIRest post:^(UNISimpleRequest *request) {
  [request setUrl:@"http://httpbin.org/post"];
  [request setHeaders:headers];
  [request setParameters:parameters];
}] asJson];
```

**Question:** How do I adapt the example for multiple files?

- The receiving end of this POST request is a PHP page.  I can change code there.

Comment: If you observer the example, parameters is a NSDictionary. it one of the key is file, and he added the file as the value. You can add one more value like @"file2":file2Obj . But this all depends on how your server is expecting the files to come in the request.

Comment: @Priyatham51 Thanks for helping. I know we can do {@"key":Value}. But in my case the key is `@"files[]"`, then I can't have duplicate keys in NSDictionary.  The alternative is to generate @"file[0]" , @"file[1]", @"file[2]"...  But I assume UNIREST as a REST library would have this scenario covered.

Comment: try putting all the files in a array and that add that array to dictionary with key files.

Comment: @Priyatham51 just tried; doesn't work.  It crashes Unirest library.  Guess I'll have to manually put together post parameters.